# Check if code module exists in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I want to get the directory of my extension in Firefox.

In Firefox 3 it works like this:

```
var file = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/extensions/manager;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIExtensionManager)
    .getInstallLocation("{my guid}");
```

In Firefox 4 you need to use the new Addon Manager like this:

```
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");

AddonManager.getAddonByID("{my guid}", function(addon) {
    addon.getResourceURL("file name"));
});
```

Since I want my extension to be compatible with both Firefox 3.x and Firefox 4.x and above, how can I check if the AddonManager.jsm is available?

Comment: In Firefox 3, you can also just do `Application.extensions.get(guid).version` so checking whether `Application.extensions` is defined is a good way of doing that.

Comment: but how can I check if it is defined?

Comment: undefined is a falsy value so just `if (Application.extensions) { /* code for Firefox 3.6 */ } else { /* code for Firefox 4 */ }`

Comment: thanks. you can add it as an answer, if you want me to vote for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to do

```
if (Application.extensions) {
  // code for Firefox 3.6
} else {
  // code for Firefox 4+
}
```

but it's a bit weird since the Firefox 4 API is asynchronous and the Firefox 3 API is synchronous.

Comment: To get round the async/sync difference, just define a handler for the async completion for FF4 and call the handler explicitly at the end of FF3 code.